# What's the largest prime number found using the Eratosthenes sieve?

Tags: prime-numbers

Just looking for the number asked in the question.  I have a reason for wanting to know.

I've googled this question and the closest I have come to an answer is this:

"The sieve of Eratosthenes is one of the most efficient ways to find all primes smaller than n when n is smaller than 10 million or so (Ref Wiki)."

Comment: What searching have you done?  That is what I would have to do to answer.

Comment: I have a reason for not putting any effort into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a record, but it appears that http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/eratosthene_en.php used Eratosthenes to find all the primes up to $100,000,000,000$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry.  That's a far cry from 10,000,000.  And that's basically all I wanted to know.